# msg.mentions.users.first(), does not run

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i am a new JS/Discord.js dev making a bot, but msg.mentions.users.first() is not working, nothing runs after this.

Code -

```
   var mentioner = msg.mentions.users.first();


        let mentiosner = msg.guild.members.cache.get(mentioner.id);



        console.log(mentiosner.nickname)

        let rand = Math.random(1,deaths.length)
        let floor =  Math.floor(rand * deaths.length)
        console.log(deaths[floor])
        console.log(rand)

        let death = new discord.MessageEmbed
        death.title = "**death'd**"
        death.description = `${mentiosner.displayName} ${deaths[floor]}`
       msg.channel.send(death)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is but maybe this will help you:
[https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#mentions\](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/commands-with-user-input.html#mentions%5C)
Hope I could help ;)
ShadowLp174